# How can I fix a broken os?

Tags: fastboot, boot, bootloader

I don't actually know if it's a broken OS, but, when I try to turn it on, the Motorola logo keeps flashing (the device is an Motorola G6). But it never actually turns on.

- When you press vol down though, it goes into a black screen that says `AP fastboot flash mode (secure)`.
- I've tried going into recovery mode, but anything other than the barcodes gets it back into the loop.
- `lsusb` doesn't detect the phone when plugged in
- Battery didn't charge past 3% when the phone worked

Comment: Did you do anything special before you phone refused to boot? Did the device ran out of free flash storage? I don't think the OS is damaged, in case the OS partition was altered there would be an error message like "vbmeta image verification failed". Android does not contain tools to recover such a situation. The common way is to perform a factory reset.

Comment: Not really, it wouldn't charge past 3% tho, but I don't think it has anything to do with that. And it had been factory rested before that happened, so I don't think it was a memory problem. Also, I can't really factory reset it now, since I'd need to go in recovery mode to do that, and I can't.

Comment: Then may be the flash memory has reached it's end of life.

Comment: How would I know?

Comment: Also, when I plug the phone in, on the fastboot screen, it doesn't appear on the my PC, like at all, even when I run "lsusb" or "adb devices"

Comment: Adb doesn't work in fastboot mode. But at least lsusb should see something if you compare the output before and after connecting your phone via USB to the PC.

Comment: It doesn't tho, that's why I'm so clueless. And no, it's not the cable